# Error in filtering by date in R: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r, if-statement, dummy-variable

I want to create a new variable in my data table in R that will be equal to 1, if the date of the event is after a certain time (2019-01-01) and will be equal to 0 otherwise. I am using the following code:

```
dt$time <- ifelse[dt$date > '2019-01-01',1,0]
```

But I am getting a mistake:

> object of type 'closure' is not subsettable.

To be honest, I don't understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong syntax, you probably meant :

```
dt$time <- ifelse(dt$date > '2019-01-01',1,0)
```

Even if the above work it will not give you correct output always because you are comparing date with string here (check `class('2019-01-01')`). You should probably use

```
dt$time <- ifelse(dt$date > as.Date('2019-01-01'), 1, 0)
```

but you don't really need `ifelse` here, you can convert the logical values after comparison to integer values.

```
dt$time <- as.integer(dt$date > as.Date('2019-01-01'))
#OR
#dt$time <- +(dt$date > as.Date('2019-01-01'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `base::ifelse` messes with variable formats. Be careful when using it. There is an alternative within `dplyr` package:

```
initial.date <- as.Date('2019-01-01')
dt$time <- dplyr::if_else(
    condition = dt$date > initial.date,
    true = 1,
    false = 0
)
```